# Do something if mysql command fails

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm trying to get the below command to do something if sql is not true

```
for filename in test.txt
do
mysql -N -e "SELECT ROLE FROM SENTRY WHERE ROLE = '$filename';"
exitcode=$?

if [ $exitcode -ne 0 ]; then
echo did not succeed
else
echo succeeded 
fi

done
```

When i run this script it returns:

```
success
success
success
```

Which is not true

test.txt contains

```
admin
test1
test2
```

select role from sentry returns

```
admin
user
```

Comment: A query that returns no results is a success in mysql. You've made an assumption about `mysql`'s exit code that does not hold.

Comment: You are right. I need to figure out a way to "if sql not true do ..."

Comment: I do not have the ability to hit against a mysql database at the moment, but if your query remains simple, you can most likely grab the output of the mysql command and do some logic on that, rather than the exit code. `SQL_OUTPUT=$(mysql -N -e "SELECT ...")`

Comment: im in the same boat right now, server is down. I think i can just throw mysql command in a variable and then "if $mysql =="" do. I think that checks for an empty variable

Comment: `select count(sentry.role) from . . . ` and test for zero?